# Inserting same value from csv to empty rows using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, upload

Good Day everyone,
I would like some help on uploading this data in mysql using php. I don't know if this question was asked already, but I can't really find answers so any help will be appreciated thank you.

As you see in the Data From CSV area that is how I will upload the data, but there are empty values in the description which I need to fill up using php. If the document are equal the description should also be equal.

[CSV Data VS Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aV6O.png)

Comment: Load CSV into table with LOAD DATA INFILE then fill empty values with UPDATE.

Comment: Good day, but what I need is for it to automatically fill those empty values before or after uploading..

Comment: *what I need is for it to automatically fill those empty values before or after uploading..* This must be performed by separate query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE
INTO TABLE tmp_table
{ importing options }
(AccountName, DocumentNo, Description);
```

Updating:

```sql
UPDATE tmp_table t1
JOIN tmp_table t2 USING (AccountName, DocumentNo)
SET t1.Description = t2.Description
WHERE t2.Description > '';
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=22c292e88fa4f9edae1c767bf81f070a

There must be only one distinct non-empty value in `Description` for each `(AccountName, DocumentNo)` pair value (i.e. more than one row with non-empty value allowed, but all these values must be the same). If not then the output is unpredictable, moreover, in some rows one non-empty value may be replaced with another non-empty value.

---

Of course this everything may be done with one (formally) query.

You may attach your CSV file as a table with `ENGINE = CSV` option then copy the data into it using

```sql
INSERT INTO tmp_table (AccountName, DocumentNo, Description)
SELECT AccountName, DocumentNo, t2.Description
FROM csv_table t1
JOIN csv_table t2 USING (AccountName, DocumentNo)
WHERE t2.Description > '';
```

But your CSV must **not** contain prefix lines which must be ignored during importing.

There must be only one non-empty value in `Description` for each `(AccountName, DocumentNo)` pair value. If not then the amount of rows in `tmp_table` will be multiplied. But you may edit the query and replace `csv_table t2` with according subquery which distincts `Description` value for each `(AccountName, DocumentNo)` pair value.

Comment: Thank you sir! Worked like a charm. Although it's a bit slow when using it with thousands of data, but it does answer my question. Thank you sir.

Comment: @DemBautista *it's a bit slow when using it with thousands of data* Create according index after data importing, it will improve UPDATE. In the second option - none may help.

Comment: Which should I index sir?

Comment: @DemBautista `CREATE INDEX idx ON tmp_table (AccountName, DocumentNo);`

Comment: Thank you so much sir, you're a life saver. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PHP for this. Just import the CSV data (with whatever tool or language you use) into a temporary table, then you fill in the gaps with SQL too, and finally push the data into the main table. That will relieve you from coding and will make the process a lot efficient & faster.

```
...Code to import CSV data to temporary table

UPDATE tmp_data
SET description = document
WHERE description = '' OR description IS NULL;

INSERT INTO main_data (account, document, description) 
SELECT account, document, description FROM tmp_data;
```

Comment: Good day thank you for helping, I tried your code already but the result in the description part is the document_no which is "123", what I need is for it to show "Description 1" , for example if the document_no row is equal to "123" then the empty Description should be = "Description 1" .

Comment: SET description = CONCAT('Description ', document)